# How to recognise single new line tokens in a flex/bison based parser and ignore multiple new lines?

Tags: parsing, flex-lexer

I want my bison based parser to recognise single new line tokens like '\n' but ignore multiple new lines so they dont have a role in the overall grammar except in situations i want just a single new line to be included after a pattern,for example leave a new line after a definition but then ignore other new lines.

So far in my lexer i just include the `[\n] { }` type of rule which ignores new lines,but want to recognise single new line tokens so i tried `[\n{1}] {return '\n';}` but it doesnt seem to work as intended.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question is actually about the lexer, so the bison tag has nothing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that `[\n{1}]` doesn't do what you think. That means: "recognize one character that can be a newline, an opening curly  bracket, a one or a closing curly bracket".

To solve this it's better to understand the criteria for priority in Flex.

1. The pattern with the bigger match has priority.
2. If the pattern has the same length, the pattern above has priority.

Try the following:

```
[\n]    {return '\n';}
[\n]+   {}
```

A single newline matches both, but uses the rule above (returns the token). More than one newline matches the second rule but not the first (it is ignored).

Comment: In my bison grammar i have this rule:PROGRAMM IDENTIFIER '\n' STARTMAIN ENDMAIN,so i want a newline after the keyword PROGRAMM and the identifier,but after making the changes you proposed, when i input a test programm like PROGRAMM test1 (then newline) STARTMAIN (then newline) ENDMAIN it says i have a invalid token in line 1 which is PROGRAMM test1.I should say i ignore tab characters also in the lexer with [ t] { }.

Comment: That seems like a completely different question, a problem either with the definition of your grammar or maybe the need of states in your lexer to differentiate when to return or not a newline token.
But this answer fits the explicit need you wrote in your question...

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your need, but if I'm right, what you need is just a single rule `[\n]+ {return '\n';}`.